# Ethernet connection not working or being detected

Tags: windows-10, ethernet

I have a laptop (windows 10) that I use an ethernet cable to connect to the internet. Today I connected the cable as usual but the ethernet cable wasn't recognised.

Connecting to the wifi works. Other people on the same network can connect fine using both the same router and same cable (so it's not a problem with the other hardware ... just my laptop).

I see in the Network Connections (Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Network Connections) that my ethernet connection is disabled and it refuses to enable.

The Device manager reports no problems with the device/drivers etc.

Things I have tried

1. Disconnect and reconnect the ethernet cable
2. Restart the router
3. Restart my laptop
4. Disable wifi on my laptop

Comment: Try disconnecting and reconnecting the Ethernet cable.

Comment: @simlev i should have put in my question that I had tried this already, I'll add a list of things that i tried before I cam up with the solution

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by going to Device Manager and disabling then enabling my Ethernet Connection

1. Open Device manager (press the Windows Key then type "Device Manager")
2. In the list Expand "Network Adapters"
3. Right click on the node that says "... Ethernet ..." and choose "Disable Device"
4. The ethernet connection will now be disabled
5. Right click on the same node and select "Enable Device" and follow the instructions to enable it

[image]

The ethernet connection might now be working.